# Are there closed-form expressions for the real and imaginary functions?

Tags: complex-analysis

By "real and imaginary functions" I mean $\operatorname{Re}(z)$ and $\operatorname{Im}(z)$.

Comment: What does closed form mean?

Comment: @JonasMeyer See my comment on Kirill's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look for closed-form expression of $\Re(z) $ as analytic functions such as $\sin(z),e^z,\sqrt {z} $ or combination of known functions or power series etc., it is impossible.

If we prove that $\Re(z) $ cannot be expressed as analytic functions,   $\Im(z)$ cannot either because They have relation $z=\Re(z) +i\Im(z) $.

Lema:  $\Re(z) $ is not analytic function.

Prove:

$z$ is complex number

$x$ and $y$ are real numbers

$$z=x+iy $$

$$\Re(z)=\Re(x+iy)=x$$
 $$\frac{d Re(z)}{d z}=\lim\limits_{ y\to 0  } \frac{d Re(x+iy)}{d (x+iy)}=\frac{\partial (x)}{\partial  x}=1 \tag1$$

$$\frac{d Re(z)}{d z}=\lim\limits_{ x\to 0  } \frac{d Re(x+iy)}{d (x+iy)}=\frac{\partial  (x)}{i \partial  y}=0 \tag2$$

If $\Re{(z)}$ is analytic function Result ($1$) and Result ($2$) must be equal. There cannot be two different limit value on a point.

You can analize all functions in same method if they are analytic or not.

If we want to check

$f(z)=f(x+iy)=U(x,y)+iV(x,y)$

$$\frac{d f(z)}{d z}=\lim\limits_{ y\to 0  } \frac{d(U(x,y)+iV(x,y))}{d (x+iy)}=\frac{\partial U (x,y)}{ \partial  x}+i\frac{\partial V (x,y)}{ \partial  x} \tag3$$

$$\frac{d f(z)}{d z}=\lim\limits_{ x\to 0  } \frac{d(U(x,y)+iV(x,y))}{d (x+iy)}=\frac{\partial U (x,y)}{ i\partial  y}+i\frac{\partial V (x,y)}{i \partial  y} =-i\frac{\partial U (x,y)}{ \partial  y}+\frac{\partial V (x,y)}{ \partial  y}\tag4$$

If $f(x+iy)$ is analytic function, the result 3 and result 4 must be equal. This means that, the function is complex-differentiable in a whole domain (holomorphic) is the same as an analytic function.

If we check real and imaginary parts.

We get the result:

$$\frac{\partial U (x,y)}{ \partial x}=\frac{\partial V (x,y)}{ \partial  y}$$

$$\frac{\partial U (x,y)}{ \partial y}=-\frac{\partial V (x,y)}{ \partial  x}$$

They are named [Cauchy–Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations)

Answer (score 2):

This is cheating, but we can use $\dfrac{z+\bar{z}}{2}$ for the real part, and 
$\dfrac{z-\bar{z}}{2i}$ for the imaginary part.

Here $\bar{z}$ is as usual the complex conjugate of $z$.

The function that takes $z$ to $\bar{z}$ is not differentiable. That puts some limitations on the *kind* of auxiliary function one could use for an expression.

**Remark:** If we don't want to allow complex conjugate as a basic operation, but are comfortable with the norm, then we can define $\bar{z}$ (for $z\ne 0)$, by $\bar{z}=\frac{|z|^2}{z}$.  However, the more natural definition goes the other way, $|z|$ as $\sqrt{z\bar{z}}$.

Comment: This doesn't make sense unless there's also a closed form expression for the complex argument function.

Comment: @proximal ...and how does one get $r$ and $\theta$ from $z$?

Comment: I've just answered that question myself: $r = |z|, \theta = \arctan(\Im(z))$, which requires both functions we're trying to define.

Comment: The whole point of this question was an attempt to define absolute value as a full function of $z$, as it is equal to $\sqrt{\Re^2(z) + \Im^2(z)}$. But those functions require the complex conjugate to define, which requires absolute value to define. It's an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

No, closed form should mean something like "easy to calculate" or "easy to manipulate", so $\Re z$ and $\Im z$ are already in closed form.

Comment: By closed form I mean independent of any conditions but the argument, in fully functional form: you can easily calculate Fibonacci numbers by the sum of the previous two numbers, but they have the closed-form expression $\frac{\phi^n - (-\phi)^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}}$.

Comment: @LeeSleek: Your Fibonacci number example is an interesting one. For very large $n$, the "closed form" does not lead to a computationally efficient evaluation method, Better is a modification of the recurrence, using an idea similar to the binary method for exponentiation.

Comment: @AndréNicolas In any case, this is not an answer to my question, when yours is close to one.

Comment: @LeeSleek Closed form is a somewhat vague concept, but your definition of closed form seems strange, and quite likely differs from how other people would understand that term.